# How to write csv file in html?

Tags: python, html, django, csv

I have read file of csv but I have a problem that how to read CSV file and save it in *table.html*?

```
import csv

html_about = ''
names = []

with open('filo.csv') as data_file:
    csv_data = csv.reader(data_file)

    for line in csv_data:
    names.append(f'{line[0]}')

html_output = '\n<ul>'

for name in names:
    html_output += f'\n\t<li>{name}</li>'

html_output += '\n</ul>'

from prettytable import PrettyTable
x = PrettyTable(line[0])
html_code = x.get_html_string()
html_file = open('table.html','w')
html_file = html_file.write(html_code)
```

Comment: Hi, what is the expected content of table.html and what does your code produce? Do you get any errors?

Comment: you create `html_output` but later you write data from `line[0]` - why? Do you have correct indentions in this code ? Do you write to  `table.html` only once ? If you write many times then you remove older version.

Comment: I want to write only once.

Comment: Could someone answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use pandas library,

it has [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), and also [pd.to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)

usage should look like this, let me know if this works for you:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filo.csv')

with open('table.html', 'w') as html_file:
    df.to_html(html_file)
```

Comment: notice: you have to install `pandas` first, using `pip install pandas`